# JavaScript do something if one of four buttons is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I'm working on a JavaScript project and now I need to find a way, how it can do the if commands, if I press one of four buttons. The code looks basically like this:

```
i=1
if(i==1){
  [[...]]
  $("#button1").click(function() {
    i++
  }
}
if(i==2) {
  [[..]]
}
```

I thought JavaScript would check the if(i==2), see, that i is 2 and do the actions, but it doesnt...

Comment: Welcome! Please take a loot at this [how to ask guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for making a better question so we can help you better.

Comment: `if(i==2)` condition would be executed only when `i` will be `2` at the run-time. In your case, `i=1`.

Comment: You can add identifiers for each button and these buttons should also have click event handlers. So, you’ll be able to do anything you need when specific button was clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You may use switch case with different button onClick. And call different function from there.

```js
$('button').on('click', function () {
  var i = 0;
  switch ($(this).attr('id')) {
    case "btn1": i+=1; break;
    case "btn2": i+=2; break;
    case "btn3": i+=3; break;
    case "btn4": i+=4; break;
  }
  console.log(i);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn1">1</button>
<button id="btn2">2</button>
<button id="btn3">3</button>
<button id="btn4">4</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses jquery (I noticed you are already using it).

You need to be able to uniquely identify individual buttons, if you add an attribute to each with an index then this is possible.

Once you have this unique identifying attribute you can create click events for individual buttons with the line: `$("button[btn-ind='2']").click( function() { ... });`. Alternatively you can apply a general click event for any button and differentiate within that click event by checking the attribute (i.e. the value of `$(this).attr("btn-ind")`.

- Buttons 1 and 2 have their own click events in the code below.
- Buttons 3 and 4 only have a a click event via the general `button` selector.

Let me know if this isn't what you wanted.

```js
$("button[btn-ind='1'").click( function() {
  console.log($(this).text() + " clicked");
});


$("button[btn-ind='2'").click( function() {
  console.log($(this).text() + " clicked");
});


$("button").click( function() {

  if ( $(this).attr("btn-ind") == "3" ) {
  
    console.log($(this).text() + " clicked");
    
  } else if ( $(this).attr("btn-ind") == "4") {
  
    console.log($(this).text() + " clicked");
    
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button btn-ind="1">Button 1</button>
<button btn-ind="2">Button 2</button>
<button btn-ind="3">Button 3</button>
<button btn-ind="4">Button 4</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're getting wrong the underlying event pattern. You are trying to use simple procedural programming to distinguish the pressed button, but this doesn't even make sense.

You should attach a different event handler to each button and then simply do what that button is supposed to do:

```
<button type="button" id="button1">1</button>
<button type="button" id="button2">2</button>
<button type="button" id="button3">3</button>
<button type="button" id="button4">4</button>

<script>

  $("#button1").on("click", () => {
    // button 1 was pressed, do what you must
  };

  $("#button2").on("click", () => {
    // button 2 was pressed, do what you must
  };

  $("#button3").on("click", () => {
    // button 3 was pressed, do what you must
  };

  $("#button4").on("click", () => {
    // button 4 was pressed, do what you must
  };

</script>
```

A much smaller code footprint can be achieved by parameterizing the buttons through an HTML attribute such as `data-*`. Do not use arbitrary, invented attributes, they are not HTML5 compliant. Here I use `data-command` attributes to show that indices are not necessary:

```
<button type="button" data-command="start">1</button>
<button type="button" data-command="faster">2</button>
<button type="button" data-command="slower">3</button>
<button type="button" data-command="stop">4</button>

<script>

  // attach event to all buttons with a data-command attribute
  $("button[data-command]").on("click", () => {
    // distinguish by data-command attribute
    switch ($(this).data("command"))
    {
      case "start":
        // perform the "start" action
        break;
      case "faster":
        // perform the "faster" action
        break;
      case "slower":
        // perform the "slower" action
        break;
      case "stop":
        // perform the "stop" action
        break;
      default:
        throw "unrecognized command (was \"" + $(this).data("command") + "\")";
    }
  };

</script>
```